# How to handle authorization for Apps Script from Chrome extension

Tags: google-apps-script, google-chrome-extension, authorization

I try to execute a Google Apps Script from my Chrome extension. My Google Apps Script uses Spreadsheet Service - it reads data from the user's spreadsheet, url of which is provided by user to my extension and then sent by extension to GAS. So, I've deployed Google Apps Script as web app, which is executed by a user accessing the web app and can be accessed by anyone. The problem is that when the script is run for the first time by a new user, the user can't see the authorization request so the script can't access the spreadsheet and send data to the extension. Everything works fine only if a user runs the script manually in the browser - only then the authorization request appears.
My question is how extension can trigger the authorization request to appear automatically?
I have read this question with answers [Running Apps Script from Chrome extension requires authorization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30671735/running-apps-script-from-chrome-extension-requires-authorization?rq=1) but there are only instructions on how to avoid authorization, which in my case can't be avoided. I would appreciate any help with this.

Update: I'm trying to use getAuthorizationUrl() as advised in the comments and now I'm stuck again. Here is the code from the Google Apps Script:

```
function doGet(e) {
  var url=e.parameter.url; 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url); 
  var authInfo = ScriptApp.getAuthorizationInfo(ScriptApp.AuthMode.FULL);
  var status=authInfo.getAuthorizationStatus();
  if (status=="NOT_REQUIRED") {
    var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
    var data = getData(sheet);
    if(!data) {
       data = '';
    }
    return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({'result': data})).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  } else {
    var authUrl=authInfo.getAuthorizationUrl();
    return authUrl;
  }
}
```

In both cases responseType of my XMLHttpRequest will be "", so how can my extension distinguish between 2 possible responses? I need something like this in the content script (don't know what to put inside if):

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(response) {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
        try {
            if (??response is authUrl) {
                //do redirect;
            }
                else {
            //process the data from the spreadsheet
            }
```

Comment: Can your extension show a webpage?

Comment: @TheMaster, there is a popup.html page where user inputs the url of his Google spreadsheet, if that is you mean. Or, I also tried to redirect user to a new tab in the browser and run script there to trigger the authorisation request - well, that works, but in this case all retrieved data is shown in this tab after authorisation is granted and script is executed. Moreover, the user can see the url of Google Apps Script and I have no idea how to close this tab after authorisation.

Comment: You could redirect to the authorization url: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/authorization-info#getauthorizationurl

Comment: @TheMaster, thank you for giving me the right direction to move, but I'm stuck again since this is my first experience in developing a chrome extension using GAS. I have updated my question.

Comment: This will work if the app is deployed as "Anyone, even anonymous". Unfortunately, I don't think you can directly get the url like that. However, you can see the url format, >So, you can create the url without gas. Even if the app is authorized, the calling function(xhr) needs to be authorized as well>eg:by sending user cookies in the request( I'm not sure how feasible this is in chrome extension ) or bearer tokens. You'll be better off  using [tag:google-sheets-api]  instead of web app.

Comment: @TheMaster, I can't even get the url for authorization in the GAS itself - when I run the script or its function directly on the script.google.com it requires authorization and after granting it, the authorization status becomes "Not_required" and getAuthorizationUrl() returns null. I can't understand how can I see this url and how I can create it without GAS. As for calling function(xhr), there is no problem with it since my extension uses OAuth 2. If the user is logged in his Google account, the calling function can access his Google sheet, but the script needs to be authorized.

Comment: *function directly on the script.google.com it requires authorization and after granting it, the authorization status becomes "Not_required"* The page you clicked "authorize/accept", that page's url contains the authorization parameters. You can also get the [authorization url params here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#creatingclient)